# Regular expression to match a number on a specific format except a given number

Tags: regex, regex-negation

We are about to send some sensitive data that in original contains date of birth and needs to be anonymized. The data file is run through a program that should anonymize the data, but I want to double check that is actually works.

The anonymizer (if it works) changes all PatientID-files in an XML-file to 19121212-1212. (The receiver of the data does not need to know if two samples originate from the same person, so there is no need for a coded ID, the same bogus ID on all samples will do fine.)

So the question is: How do I expand the regular expression `PatientID="\d{8}-\d{4}"` so that it matches all PatientID-fields except when `PatientID="19121212-1212"`? (Which will give me no match if the anonymizer worked.)

I have tried making something out of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781554/regular-expression-matching-everything-except-a-given-regular-expression) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) which tangents my question, but I have not been able to produce a solution from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I was about to hit send I got an idea and it worked. Instead of not sending the question I post it with the solution instead.

```
PatientID="((?!19121212-1212).){13}"
```